# xquery error : while using the where clause

Tags: xquery

```
{
    for $movie in distinct-values(doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie)
    where count(doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie[title=$movie/title]) = count(distinct-values(doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie/source))
    return
    <title> {$movie/title} </title> 
}
```

In this particular query I am tryin to : Find movie titles that are offered from all sources in the "movies" document. I am getting an error on the line of the where clause. the error is : Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:anyAtomicType

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `distinct-values()` returns distinct string values, so you are trying to use an xpath expression on a string. `$movie/title` evaluates to `(xs:string)/title` which is invalid and throws an exception.

But the way I understand your goal, I don't think that query will return the results you want. Try this solution for returning movie titlea that are offered from all sources:

```
let $sources-distinct-all := count(distinct-values(doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie/source))
for $title in distinct-values(doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie/title) 
let $sources-distinct-movie := count(distinct-values(doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie[title eq $title]/source))
where ($sources-distinct-all eq $sources-distinct-movie)
return $title
```